# Query Works in Oracle SQL Developer but not in Microsoft Query

Tags: excel, oracle

I've spent the last two days going through Google and searching around this site for help on this but none of the suggested solutions work/make sense to me sadly. Essentially I have a code that works fine in Oracle SQL Developer that I am trying to place into an Excel workbook so that people without SQL knowledge could simply change the start/stop times in a few cells and gather the necessary information they need for their reports.

I tried testing the below code to see if it worked before I tried to link it to specific cells but sadly it failed so i have not tried setting the variables to cells yet.

The Code is as follows:

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

define start_dateA = TO_DATE('2017-07-05_00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"_"HH24:MI:SS');
define stop_dateB = TO_DATE('2017-07-05_23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD"_"HH24:MI:SS');

select tdate, FRSTOL, TOSTOL,   DEVCOD, USR_ID, PRTNUM, TRNQTY
from mytable
where 
tdate BETWEEN &start_dateA AND &stop_dateB
and (FRSTOL like 'A%'
OR FRSTOL like 'B%'
OR FRSTOL like 'C%'
OR FRSTOL like 'E%'
OR FRSTOL like 'F%'
OR FRSTOL like 'L%'
OR FRSTOL like 'P%'
OR FRSTOL like 'R%'
OR FRSTOL like 'T%')

order by usr_id, tdate
```

The error I receive when i try to run this is ORA-00922. I'm about 95% sure there is an issue with the define statements, as when replace the variables start_dateA and stop_dateB with the actual values it works fine. Please note i will need both the date and time components for what I'm working on. Also I only have ReadOnly privileges for the server so I unable/do not have the knowledge to make changes to the tables or servers themselves.

Also not sure if I'm allowed to ask two questions but if someone could also help with how to go about setting start_dateA and &stop_dateB to specific cells as well that would be greatly appreciated as that is the hurdle I face after figuring out this step.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: The statement `SET NOCOUNT ON;` is TSQL (for Microsoft SQL Server). Think hard about why you tried to use that for Oracle.

Comment: `define` is a SQL*Plus command not an Oracle database command. Other client tools for Oracle probably implement it for compatibility. I do not know of any Microsoft client tools that implement `define`.

Comment: Mike, the statement SET NOCOUNT ON was only added when I attempted to use it in Microsoft Query. I only added it when i first encountered issues with the code working when attempting to run it through Excel and several Google searches suggested I Include it.

Comment: Shannon, Thank you for verifying the "define" portion of the code is the issue. Could you suggest how I could work around not using this statement but still maintain having a variable?

Comment: I doubt that searches suggested you try to use a statement that's specific to SQL Server when you're querying an Oracle database. I think more careful reading is in order. Some background study might be worthwhile, too.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to solve the problem by writing brittle define statements, I recommend you refactor the date predicate a bit w.r.t. the define statements:

```
define dtA=2017-07-05_00:00:00
define dtB=2017-07-05_23:59:59
define fmt='YYYY-MM-DD"_"HH24:MI:SS'

tdate between TO_DATE('&dtA', '&fmt') and TO_DATE('&dtB', '&fmt')
```

Comment: Jeff, unfortunately the code you provided resulted in the same error message appearing.

Comment: Please review the factored code and let me know what you think.

Comment: Jeff, Thank you for your responses thus far. The code you provided does work when ran through Oracle SQL Developer however when I attempt to run it through Excel i receive the following error "ora-00900 invalid sql statement". Someone above stated that Excel likely does support "Define" as its an SQL*plus command and not an Oracle command. I'm at a loss as to how to fix this.

Comment: Since I don't see what excel is doing, I suggest you trace what excel executed then you might know what to tweak in the excel implementation. You can trace the excel execution and see the exact SQL statement text in the trace file. Alternatively, you'll want to see if excel supports placeholders in SQL statements. If it does, then proceeding will be quite easy.